# Form radios to control visible/invisible code elements(ajax)

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to use ajax to make some form elements become visible or invisible based on what choice you make on some radio buttons.

There are two choices: "tag" or "form" for the radios. "tag" is default and the body field is visible to begin with. But if you click the "form" choice instead the body field disappears. Then I want to be able to click on "tag" again and make the body field visible again but it is here I run into trouble.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function format_and_filter_form_protocol_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {

   $form['protocol_form_view_radios'] =  array(
                             '#type' => 'radios',
                             '#title' => 'Input by:',
                             '#options' => array('taging','form'),
                             '#default_value' => 0,
                             '#ajax' => array(
                                              'callback' => 'format_and_filter_change_input_callback',
                                              'wrapper' => 'body-add-more-wrapper',
                                              ),
                    '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
                             '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
                             '#weight' => -31,
                             );

}

function format_and_filter_change_input_callback($form,&$form_state) {

   if ($form_state['input']['protocol_form_view_radios'] == 0) {
     $form['body']['#access'] = TRUE;
   }
   else {
     $form['body']['#access'] = FALSE;
   }

  return $form['body'];
}
```

Does anyone have any explanation why $form['body']['#access'] = TRUE doesn't make the body field visible again?
I've checked the $form array and seen that $form['body']['#access'] actually gets set to 1 when $form_state['input']['protocol_form_view_radios'] == 0 is true.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wayward space in the #ajax callback

```
'callback' => 'format_and_filter_change_inpu t_callback',
```

Is that also present in your code?

Comment: No, it's a mistake in the question only.